What did statisticians use to quickly find p-values before applets were popularized in the late 2010s?
New statistics student here, I found out from my professor today that actually, applets that simulate repetitions of samples weren't really around until the late 2010s, which was really surprising to me since they seem so simple- like something that would've been around for a while. What was used to quickly find p-values before these were around?

Computers have been used to calculate p values long before 2010. However, if you open to the back of most any introductory statistics book and you will find tables of p values.  The tail probabilities for various distributions (and various parameterizations) were all calculated and tabulated for reference.  If you had taken a statistics course circa 2010 (when I was an undergrad), you would have computed p values in class via this method.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Erika, also we do not need simulations to get p values for certain distributions. A lot of hypothesis testing is done on sample means which, if the sample size is sufficiently large enough, we know what its distribution is. Then we can just look up our value on that distribution. Most reference books still do have tables of p values. Simulations are sometimes used for intractable distributions often found in Bayesian inference, which don't use p values in the hypothesis testing sense.

As well as tables, students could go to statistics labs and program small computers to calculate p-values for a given distribution from the mid 1970s.

Could you elaborate on what you mean with "applet"? To me it just means a small application/program, but I feel like it means something more specific here.

@AkselA R, Excel, Python, SAS, pick your poison. The suggestion being each of these uses numerical methods to solve complicated if not intractable integrals to report $p$-values to an arbitrary level of precision. Rather than applet we could more generally say "software".

If you mean specifically by simulation, I was writing code for stats computation as an undergraduate by late 1981, using statistical software programs soon after and was definitely simulating p values for permutation tests by 1984 (likely earlier,  but definitely by then). None of the ideas or approaches involved was remotely new at the time. Simulating distributions of test statististics was not that unusual in the 60s (see Lilliefors, 1967 for example). But it goes waay back. Galton used specially constructed dice to perform simulation....

... Outside simulation, p-values were computed as early as the 1750s. By 1900, Pearson computed p values for chi squared tests and called them "P"

@AkselA We're using the Rossman/Chance applets- mainly just for finding p-values right now.

I am from the early 2010s, what are applets? Is this some software that you put on your Android phone? This question is not very clear or very broad. "What did statisticians use to quickly find p-values?" That's an incredibly long list. It is also unclear what is different now with these 'applets'. I am unaware of newly emerging 'applets' that came up in the last decade and make computation of p-values more easy. Maybe it is just me, but it is confusing and this should really be clarified in the question.

"simulate repetitions" this sounds like Monte Carlo method, and apparently following Wikipedia „In the 1930s, Enrico Fermi first experimented with the Monte Carlo method while studying neutron diffusion, but he did not publish this work“.

"weren't really around until the late 2010s " This should be specified more clearly. A lot of statistical software is several decades old. Maybe the question is about some specific situationwhere the 2010 mark makes sense? This should be clarified or otherwise the question is speculative, what is it exactly about?

@Erika The internet archive has records of the Rossman page beginning in 2003.

Simple tables of $p$-values were in lots of places, such as the back of every book.  The industrial-grade reference for statisticians needing lots of distributions would be something like the Biometrika tables

or for mathematics more generally, Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables.  Many middle-aged statisticians will have a copy, possibly inherited from a retired colleague
For example, I just opened Volume II of the Biometrika tables at table 25, which has the non-centrality parameter for a $\chi^2$ distribution to give  power from 0.25 to 0.99 with degrees of freedom from 1 to 100
Switching to computer happened fairly early, especially for practising statisticians. I didn't really use tables even when I was a student, except during exams when a computer wasn't available.

There is an interesting subhistory here.  I wish I remembered the reference in The American Statistician.  Original tables showed tail areas as a function of ordinates.  Biometrika refused to let Fisher reproduce the tables in a new book he was writing so he inverted the calculations to give test-statistic ordinates as a function of tail areas.  That’s what let to the awful “significance” dichotomization that we still see today.

When I sat my A-levels in '93, we were still provided with such tables.

@FrankHarrell what a fun story. It would appear you are referring to Kennedy-Shaffer's 2019 TAS article (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2018.1537891); the story you give is in the first full paragraph of page 4.

That's a super article but the one I was referring to explained how the troubled British economy caused Biometrika to refuse Fisher's request for reproduction of tables in Fisher's book, leading Fisher to invert the tables to not face copyright issues.

A 2013 article in Chance corroborates @FrankHarrell's comment: War, Enmity, and Statistical Tables, namely "Fisher may have introduced tables ... because he was prevented by copyright restriction from publishing the tables in their original form" & "it may be that the enforcement of those copyright restrictions resulted in part from the economic difﬁculties faced by the journal Biometrika after World War I and in signiﬁcant part from the copyright being controlled by Karl Pearson" (p. 8, ellipses mine)

I've never used an applet to get a p-value. I know they are there, but I've never needed them. The ones I've seen are too simplistic for nearly any of the work I do (I'm retired, but not completely retired). I think applets are too user friendly and make it too easy to make preposterous assumptions. Maybe there are situations where they are a sensible option, or maybe there are some more sophisticated ones these days.
Also, I never just need a p value. People who have read my posts for a while know I am pretty far off on the "anti-p-value" end of the spectrum, and I won't go into it again here, but I always need something more - parameter estimates, standard errors, etc.
I'm 65 and I can remember using tables to do this. Computers that could do this were available from the beginning of my career, but they weren't always available to me.
For most of my career, though, I used SAS or R to find p values. Their abilities have gotten more and more sophisticated over the decades. I'm glad for that. Programing the problems was often tricky (I am not a programmer) and tables are not remotely as useful.

Here's a short timeline based on personal experience.
Academics had access to SAS and SPSS on mainframes in the 1960's and 1970's.  (My professional introduction to statistics was supporting PhD students when I was a mainframe computer operator.)  Many people relied on tables, as they had since the late 17th century, and used adding machines (through the 1960's) and the first hand-held scientific calculators (c. 1974, which cost about one month's salary for an assistant professor) for computing summary statistics, simple regressions, and ANOVA.
In the 1970's and 1980's I wrote my own statistical functions (inverse t distributions, inverse Normal, etc) for minicomputers and then PCs in C and Fortran (and even a bunch in AWK, because it did not require compilation), relying on the excellent repository of algorithms published throughout the 1960's and 1970's in Applied Statistics and TOMS.
By 1990 coding at this level was no longer necessary, because several statistical software platforms survived early competition (to see which were sufficiently accurate and stable) and became widely available.  The price for some of the better ones, such as S-Plus or Systat, was the equivalent of \$4,000 today (or much more for SAS).
By the late 1990's people were publishing code in R and starting around 2000 there was a rapid adoption of that platform, especially by people with more time than money (students and academics ;-).

BTW, back in the dark ages (before the end of the 20th century ;-), it was routine to learn how to interpolate in tables and perform numerical calculations (using Simpson's method, Newton's method, and so on) in basic high school math courses.  People who paid attention were able to calculate p-values accurately and quickly using pencil and paper.  Even in 1977 John Tukey devoted the first few pages of his book on EDA to simple computing methods (such as finding common logarithms and square roots): the inner covers of that book, instead of sporting the usual blurbs by reviewers, contain simple useful tables.

Supported in R's predecessor S too I believe

"My professional introduction to statistics was supporting PhD students when I was a mainframe computer operator."
And there is the origin story for who is, in my informal estimation, likely one of the most influential and helpful statisticians of the era.

When I went to high school in the 00's we used TI-83's for some statistical computations.

(Westernelectric555/Wikipedia)
I remember performing t-tests and OLS regressions on it, both of which would have returned p-values. In either case we'd store the data in lists, select the function, set the various parameters, and let it compute. The output from a one sample single sided t-test might have looked something like this:
T-Test
 μ>10
 z=5.055900531
 p=1.0857768e-5
 x=11.2
 Sx=1.3
 n=30

You could also use functions for various cumulative distributions to get p-values, similarly to how you can do it using tables.
The TI-83 was released in 1996, and skimming through the manual, I think its predecessor (TI-82, 1993) had similar capabilities. This means that students using "applets" to calculate p-values, if these functions qualifies as that, has been going on for at least 30 years.

Statisticians used to use various tables, and, as I understand it, the tables became dog-eared at the place where the 95% confidence interval was---corresponding to a p-value of .05---hence it was easier to look up that value by going right to the dog-eared page.  So the p-value of .05 (corresponding to a 95% confidence interval) is really quite arbitrary.  They made their way into publications purely by the convenience of manually looking them up in those tables.  Indeed, deciding that something is statistically significant because it would only occur by chance five times out of a hundred, instead of, say, six times out of a hundred, is a bit foolish and can obfuscate relationships that may truly exist.  But the field is slowly changing, and there is theoretically less reliance on the p-value alone now in some journals and fields of study.  Sample size, achieved power, and other rational interpretations also have some importance.
